# spaCy custom NER are not working for new data set

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to create few custom NER for my use case.

This is a sample of my training data:

```
[[' webex enable or disable auto join from connected video device advised user to raise a iiq request to get webex access.  hence closing this ticket getting error while joing webex since i got a replacement lap top i have not been able to access webex 954 995 0444 9 30am 6pm thurs mon getting error while joing webex.',
  {'entities': [[1, 62, 'ISSUE'],
    [63, 118, 'RESOLVE_ACTION'],
    [147, 178, 'ISSUE'],
    [193, 212, 'USER_ACTIVITY']]}],
 [' virtual desktop infrastructure vdi performance or latency issues or slow response education vdi user was getting vdi slowness issue while working on it.  i have guide to user kindly logoff your vdi machine and login back after 10 minutes.  user was getting vdi slowness issue while working on it.  vdi slowness.',
  {'entities': [[1, 47, 'ISSUE'],
    [51, 65, 'ISSUE'],
    [69, 96, 'ISSUE'],
    [183, 238, 'RESOLVE_ACTION']]}]]
```

My code is below:

```
ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")
for _, annotations in train_data:
    for ent in annotations.get('entities'):
        ner.add_label(ent[2])
disable_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']
import random 
from spacy.util import minibatch, compounding
from pathlib import Path

with nlp.disable_pipes(*disable_pipes):
    optimizer =nlp.resume_training()
    
    for iteration in range(100):
        
        random.shuffle(train_data)
        losses = {}
        
        batches = minibatch(train_data,size=compounding(1, 16, 1.001))
        for batch in batches:
            text,annotation = zip(*batch)
            print (text,annotation)
            nlp.update(text,annotation,drop=0.5,losses=losses,sgd=optimizer)
            print("Losses",losses)

output_dir = '/<my model path>/models'
if output_dir is not None:
    output_dir = Path('/my model path>/models')
    if not output_dir.exists():
        output_dir.mkdir()
    nlp.meta['name'] = "new_model"  # rename model
    nlp.to_disk(output_dir)
    print("Saved model to", output_dir)

#Testing model on training data set itself

for text, _ in train_data:
    doc = nlp2(text)
    print ('Entities',[(ent.text,ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])
    displacy.render(nlp2(doc.text), style="ent", jupyter=True)
```

My models are returning the labels for my training data, but they are not returning anything for any other sample data / text.

Comment: Like the answer said, not enough detail here to be sure what the issue is, but one note - it looks like you're rolling your own training loop. That hasn't been recommended since v3 was released over a year ago. The new config-based training is much easier and helps avoid weird mistakes. I suggest you go through the spaCy course for an introduction to it. https://course.spacy.io/en/

Answer (score 1):

Not enough rep to comment.
What is `nlp2`? I think it should be `nlp`, the one you are updating.

Edit:
It seems to be an issue of "catastrophic forgetting", if you are training on these entities with just 2 examples. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65939855/spacy-custom-name-entity-recognition-ner-catastrophic-forgetting-issue), and [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/6846). Also [this](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/9940).

Comment: thats a typoo while copy paste, I was using `nlp` not `nlp2`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The issue is with the training, cleaning the training with crisp labelling helped to fix the issue